# ArcMap maps don't print at exactly 1:24000 scale

Tags: arcmap, scale

I'm printing out USGS topo maps, that when printed should be in at a 1:24,000 scale. However, when measuring the physically printed maps, the 1 mile scale bar does not match my physical 1:24,000 ruler (the scale bar is always 0.95 miles long by the ruler).

I imagine some type of scaling is happening somewhere, but I have been unable to solve this. The data frame is set to 1:24,000, and the paper size in print setup is correct.

Comment: Try exporting to PDF first and then printing from there. Issues like this are usually down to printer settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, exporting to a PDF then printing from there is my usual procedure. Though I have tried printing from both a PDF and directly from ArcMap and get the same result

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the print settings.

Comment: Could it be a projection issue ?